# show_last parameter stopped working in plot function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

the show_last parameter in plot function just stopped working properly since the last few days.

It basically ignores the parameter in both v4 and v5.

Can someone check please.

Kevin

Comment: No issues here. Can you share your code and a screnshot of your chart?

Comment: It is fixed by TV.

Answer (score 0):

It's "working" for me, just not the way it's supposed to.
When combined with "offset" it starts adding them together.
I.e. offset = 10 and show_last = 10 equals 20 plots.
Still looking for where to submit a report.

I'll add a code sample here just in case:

```
plot(someNumber ,color=color.red, linewidth=1,style=plot.style_circles, title="forecast 1", offset=10, show_last=10)
```

Comment: I use offset too. I can see now the issue is fixed.